# how can I deserialise specific JSON fields within a JSON object to be either a List or an Object in java

Tags: java, json, deserialization

So, I need to deserialise a JSON object that has the following format:

```
 "items": [{
       "field": {},
        "actions": [
         {}
        ],
         }, 
         {
         "field": {},
         "actions": {}
         }
    ]
```

Catch 22
i.e The JSON being received has a field called "actions" that may be a list or an object based on which 'items' object is being analysed.
Consequently, trying to parse the JSON into java using Gson, I either get an error "expecting BEGIN_ARRAY but got BEGIN_OBJECT" or
"expecting BEGIN_OBJECT but got BEGIN_ARRAY".

How can I deserialize that magical actions field into either an object or a List of objects depending on the encompassing object without first passing it to the front end? Willing to use jackson.